# HazelcastSerializationException after moving class to a different package

Tags: java, microservices, hazelcast

I am running an embedded hazelcast deployment and storing a `ConcurrentMap<String, MyType>`, where the type of value in the map is my custom class.

### **MyType**

```
public class MyType implements Serializable {
   private MyTag tag;
   ...
}
```

One of its fields is an interface `MyTag`.

### **MyTag**

```
public interface MyTag<T> {
}
```

And I have a class containing several enum implementations of `MyTag` interface:

### **MyTags**

```
public class MyTags {

   public static enum Integers implements MyTag<Integer> {
      INT_TAG1,
      INT_TAG2,
      ...
   } 
  
    public static enum Strings implements MyTag<String> {
      STRING_TAG1,
      ...
   }
   
   ...
}
```

After moving `MyTags` class to a different package and redeploying one of my services (with `MyType` in the new package) upon attempting a get on the map, an exception is thrown:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: old.package.MyTags$Strings
```

How could I protect myself from this situation when deploying on a production environment?

Comment: How do you currently [serialize](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/serialization/interface-types.html) your custom type?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I've extended my question now to show a structure more similar to the actual structure in my project. (I can't share the code base). From what I've read in the documentation part you've sent the `MyType` tag is serialized by implementing `Serializable`, whereas about the `MyTag` fields my best guess is Hazelcast uses `JavaDefaultSerializers.EnumSerializer`.

Comment: In general, use of Java serialization in cluster environments is something one shouldn't do in production because it's brittle and slow.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `Serializable` depends on the class remaining the exact same. A moved class is no longer the same class. Select [one of the other options](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/serialization/interface-types.html) that Hazelcast has for serialization of objects. See [Comparing Serialization Options](https://hazelcast.com/blog/comparing-serialization-options/) for some more guidance on the different options.

Comment: So assuming I'll make the `MyTag<T>` interface extend `DataSerializable` across all my services (and have those enums in `MyTags` override `writeData()` and `readData()` methods), then if I deploy a new version of one of my services with the class `MyTags` moved to a different package would it still work? (I'm sorry if what I'm saying is unclear, I just want this example to accurately resemble my actual use case)

Comment: `MyType` should be `DataSerializable`, not the enums themselves if I understand https://groups.google.com/g/hazelcast/c/vIr9ubAvvnQ correctly. But maybe you can ask a different question specifically about `DataSerializable` and enums to get a better answer on that.